# Strange Behavior in HttpWebRequest when Saving XDocument to Body

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, httpwebrequest, linq-to-xml

I discovered some strange behavior when attempting to sent a POST request using the `HttpWebRequest` class targeting .NET 4.  This may only have to do with `XDocument` object I'm attempting to send misbehaving, or I'm not understanding the difference between the `Save()` method and `ToString()` method of `XDocument`.

Calling the following will result in the ContentLength of the request to be set to **316** for my specific `XDocument` when saved to the stream:

```
using(var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    xDoc.Save(stream, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
}
```

This was causing the server to not understand my request body.  Using fiddler I captured the XML being uploaded and then copy & pasted the raw XML into Fiddler's composer window.  Upon sending this request to the server it surprisingly responded without issue.  When I inspected the headers I noticed that Fiddler calculated **313** for ContentLength.

I attempted a few experiments to get to the bottom of this such as setting the ContentLength value first (since I knew what value should be for this specific request), but saving to the stream would always result in an exception stating that data is longer than the expected ContentLength.  Finally, I settled on this code workaround for stringifying the `XDocument` which causes the `HttpWebRequest` to calculate the correct ContentLength:

```
using(var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(xDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
}
```

The above calculates **313** and allows the server to respond correctly.

Why would saving directly to the stream vs writing data from the `ToString()` method cause `HttpWebRequest` to calculate different ContentLength header values?  Is this a bug/known issue?

**EDIT**: As requested here's a MCVE to illustrate this (the API of the program I'm connecting to is awful, my apologies for their mess):

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("PVDM_HTTPINTERFACE",
        new XElement("FUNCTION",
            new XElement("NAME", "LoginUserEx3"),
            new XElement("PARAMETERS",
                new XElement("ENTITYID", 1),
                new XElement("USERNAME", "testadmin"),
                new XElement("PASSWORD", "12345"),
                new XElement("CLIENTPINGABLE", false),
                new XElement("REMOTEAUTH", false)
            )
        )
    )
);

HttpWebRequest requestWrittenWithString = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost");
requestWrittenWithString.Method = "POST";
HttpWebRequest requestWrittenWithSave = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost");
requestWrittenWithSave.Method = "POST";

//Save directly to stream
using(var stream = requestWrittenWithSave.GetRequestStream())
{
    xDoc.Save(stream, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
}

long saveContentLength = requestWrittenWithSave.ContentLength; //316

//StreamWriter with ToString() method
using(var stream = requestWrittenWithString.GetRequestStream())
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(xDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
}

long toStringContentLength = requestWrittenWithString.ContentLength; //313
```

Comment: Without a good [mcve], impossible to say for sure. But "three extra bytes" in the context of text written by .NET almost always means you didn't suppress the UTF8 "BOM" at the beginning of the stream. This theory is reinforced by your observation that saving the XML to a string first works; strings don't have BOMs. In theory, other text reading code should not have a problem with that, but maybe you're dealing with one that does.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'll write one up, I thought the code provided was enough, but I'll add something.  I have a workaround, but I'm curious on this behavior.  Can you point me in the right direction to educate myself about UTF8 BOMs?  I've never dealt with that term before (other than wikipedia since I've already looked up some basic info about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the incomplete code example provided (which does not even compile, never mind produce exactly the results described, since the second scenario uses an undeclared variable `requestDoc` and does not emit the XML declaration to the stream), I am reasonably confident that you are in fact getting the UTF8 BOM in the stream in your first scenario.

I'm not aware of a setting in the `XDocument` class itself that would control this. But it's simple enough to explicitly specify the `TextWriter` to use for the output, and the default encoding for `StreamWriter` doesn't include a BOM (as you have already demonstrated in the second scenario).

Something like this should fix your problem in the first scenario:

```
using (var stream = requestWrittenWithSave.GetRequestStream())
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    xDoc.Save(writer, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
}
```

Of course, you could instead just use the `XDocument.ToString()` method, as in your second example. Either way is fine.

For future reference, please re-read the information at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see what is meant by "MCVE". You can save a lot of duplicated effort on the part of answerers, and increase the likelihood of an answer at all, if you provide a good MCVE.

Comment: Yeahhh...copy & paste error where I forgot to change the variable names, my bad (fixed it though).  Thanks for all the info though.  Truly appreciated.